# iPhone 5s forwarding automatically to another phone in the household after iOS 8 is installed

Tags: iphone

My son updated his 5s to ios 8 and now for some reason when I call his phone if he doesn't answer it will ring to my daughter's phone and vice versa.   I have looked on both phones and cannot figure out why. The forward feature is not on.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are having is due to the Facetime feature "**iPhone Cellular Calls**" which allows you to "Use your iPhone cellular connection to make **and receive** calls on devices **signed into your iCloud account** when they are nearby and on Wi-Fi."  This is fine if all of the devices are your own so that you can answer the call on any of your iDevices but obviously not a good idea for multiple people.

Are all of the phones signed into the same [primary] iCloud account? `Settings > iCloud`

If so, you have 2 options.

1. Log them out of the primary account and sign in using their own personal AppleID accounts.

If you were using a single iCloud account so everyone has access to a shared account for Music/Movie/App purchases, you should switch over to the new [iOS 8 Family Sharing](https://www.apple.com/icloud/family-sharing) feature.

If you haven't created their own AppleID accounts because they were under 13 or you didn't want to include your credit card on their account profile, with the Family Sharing feature, you can create accounts for each child that is automatically part of Family Sharing and all purchases must be approved by you first. See [this Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT201084) for more details.

2. Turn off the **iPhone Cellular Calls** option in the `Settings > Facetime` screen.  This will stop the calls from going to multiple devices for now but in the long run, it would be best to set up multiple AppleIDs and start using the Family Sharing feature.

Tip: When you switch over to the Family Sharing, you can either use the old shared iCloud as your own (the Organizer) or create your own personal account. 
 When setting up the Family Sharing, one of the screens will ask if you want to share your purchases or use a different account.  Choose the different account option and use the old shared account.  This 2nd method will share all the previous purchases made under the shared account out to all family members but gives you the option to NOT share your own purchases.  This is helpful for parents to purchase items that the rest of the family shouldn't have access to.

If you want to purchase something that should be shared, either sign into the App Store using the old shared account (just remember to sign out and back into your own account) or simply use one of your kids devices.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

...also. i have 5 phones on a shared itunes (iCloud) account and after IOS 8.0.2 all of our phones started ringing when someone called 1 of the phones. This was happening on wifi only.

turn off iPhone cellular calls under "settings", "facetime" as the handoff will still work if your on wifi even though it is turned off.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is Settings - phone - calls on other devices - switch to off.

Answer (score 0):

Select "settings"
Select "general"
Select "handoff"
Turn "off"

You will note: this is only available on iphone5 or later. I had this problem when upgrading my 5 and my 4, but only calls to my 4 would get forwarded to my 5. Turning this feature off on my iPhone 5 has seemed to clear up the issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by FaceTime. There is a setting `iPhone Mobile Calls`:

> Use your iphone mobile connection to make and receive calls on devices signed in to your icloud account when they nearby and on wifi.

Turn this feature off.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off your Handoff! It is only available for IPhone 5 and up. Go to settings, general. Handoff &Suggested App and turn it off!

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Personal iPhone 5 and a iPhone 6 for work. My work phone would ring if I didn't answer my personal phone. I turned off the FaceTime over cellular (as indicated above) on my work phone only, and it no longer rings when my personal phone does. However, I have the Handoff feature set to *on*, on both phones. So, Handoff does not affect this.

Answer (score -1):

Power the phone off and back on. If that doesn't work, then try a reset, hold the sleep/wake and home buttons together until you see the Apple logo and then release. This will make the phone reboot. This will not affect your data.

Answer (score -2):

I called apple and ios 8 has a feature called Hand Off that comes with the [Continuity feature set](https://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/continuity/). You have to go in and turn those off to make it stop.

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved by expanding on "you have to go in and turn those off" to provide explicit, step-by-step, instructions for "going in" and "turning off" things.  Answers that aren't fully spelled on out Ask Different tend to get down voted. For more information on how Ask Different and the StackExchange Q&A format works please see our [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).